# Simplify eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query which works perfectly fine, but i was wondering if i can even more simplify this query. Right now i have to get the order with order_status_histories with order_status where is_current is set to true. Below is the returned JSON, all i need is the order_status object so that i can check for order_status->title. I will check order_status->title with a string if its "Pending" do some stuff.

**Query:**

```
$order = Order::with('customer')
     ->with(['order_status_histories' => function($query) {
          $query->with('order_status')
                ->where('is_current', true);
    }])
    ->where('sp_id', $request->user()->sp_id)
    ->where('id', $request->order_id)
    ->first();
```

**Result**

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "sp_id": 1,
    "branch_id": 2,
    "customer_id": 1,
    "driver_id": null,
    "number": "1",
    "order_date": "2021-01-28 09:00:00",
    "duration": "60",
    "end_time": "02:00:05",
    "sub_total": 25,
    "vat": null,
    "coupon_code": null,
    "sp_coupon_code": null,
    "discount": "0",
    "total": 31,
    "lat": "54.366669",
    "long": "24.466667",
    "address": "72 Broadwalk, Crawley, Sussex",
    "note": "Testing",
    "area": "Sheikh Zaid Market",
    "city": "Abu Dhabi",
    "rejected_reason": null,
    "order_review": null,
    "payment_type": "Cash On Deivery",
    "transaction_id": "ahsdfkjasdkfasdhfasdf823426",
    "created_at": "2021-07-31T13:43:05.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-31T13:43:05.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Muhammad Usman ",
        "email": "usman@gmail.com",
        "phone": "00923163506994",
        "is_active": 1,
        "image": "images/ef8dfc3bfd1b6d0e4bf4cd0dfcf22sw3.png",
        "remember_token": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-02T15:16:24.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-02T15:16:24.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    "order_status_histories": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "order_id": 5,
            "order_status_id": 1,
            "driver_id": null,
            "is_current": "1",
            "status_keyword": "Pending",
            "admin_user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-07-30T13:28:18.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-30T13:28:18.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "order_status": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Pending",
                "keyword": "pending",
                "color": null,
                "app_title": null,
                "email_title": null,
                "notification_title": null,
                "flow": null,
                "created_at": "2021-07-30T15:21:45.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-07-30T15:21:45.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            "driver": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**How I check the title right now:**

```
if($order->order_status_histories->first()->order_status->title == 'Pending')
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Use nested `with()`: `order_status_histories.order_status`

Comment: The query is simple and readable, no need to simplify

Comment: If `order_status_histories.order_status` is always supposed to have one result only in this specific use case, you can make a separate relationship for this to omit the call to `first()`

Comment: If I get that right, you're checking the status of the order which is determined by the most recent `order_status_history` entry. Instead of writing this code in the logic, you could write an accessor to return the order status or a method to check for a specific status (e.g. `$order->isPending()` or `$order->hasStatus('pending')`

Comment: thats exactly what I'm trying to do, but can you please provide some more details in the answer how this isPending() function or hasStatus() funciton is going to work